# knox S3 upload corrupted or truncated file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

This is a brain teaser question where I actually know the answer.  I'm throwing a bounty on it because it represents a valuable Node programming safety tip (and that's the first hint).

- Hint 2: In an HTTP request, what are the units of the "Content-Length" header field?

I'm using

```
var knox = require('knox');
var s3 = knox.createClient({
    key: ...,
    secret: ...,
    bucket: ...
});

// The bug is below:

var stringVal = JSON.stringify(<2d javascript array from a large spreadsheet>)

var req = s3.put(path + filename, {
    'Content-Length': stringVal.length,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
req.end(stringVal);
```

The resulting upload is either truncated or otherwise corrupted.  We have `stringVal.length === 322889`, and the resulting S3 item size matches that.  But downloading and reloading the file results in a string which has length `322140`.  No errors show up along the way until trying to JSON.parse the string which (predictably) results in a syntax error.

What's up?

Comment: If the S3 item size matches what's expected, the problem must be in your download code.  Could you show that, please?

Comment: The downloaded file is also exactly the same size as the S3 item size. And I'm downloading with S3-Fox.  However the reloaded string has the smaller length.

Comment: Well, it's hard to diagnose your problem without seeing all the code.  I would try starting with something smaller, and seeing if there's a discrepancy between what goes in and what comes out.  If there isn't, it's probably a size thing, though I'm not sure why it would be.  There's nothing magic about the number 322140 (not a power of two, in particular), so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I have a confession.  I actually know what the problem is, and have posted this as a question because it is one of the most subtle bugs I've come across in a long time.  All the code you need is in the question.  It took me half a day to narrow the problem down to this, and it still had me stumped for a couple hours after that.  Hint: Why does Node implement a "Buffer" type?

Comment: Ah.  Well, based on your hint, it must be an encoding issue, as the reason Node implements the Buffer object is to handle binary date that's not necessarily Unicode.  Unfortunately, I can't see clear to the answer proper, so I'm gonna let someone else run with it from here...will look forward to seeing the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source of the `knox`-module (https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/blob/master/lib/client.js) you can learn that it uses standard `http`-requests.

`req.write` and `req.end` converts strings from 'utf8' by default (http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding).

So what really happens is that you by accident cut off the end of the string by setting the string-length instead of the number of bytes in the 'Content-Length'-field. The server throws away everything longer than that; so when you parse the string you get an error.

Quickest fix would be:

```
'Content-Length': new Buffer(stringVal).length,
```

Or even faster: just remove the 'Content-Length'-line.

Comment: We have a winner!  Thanks for playing! As you noted he safety tip is that the Content-length is measured in bytes while string length is measured in characters.  Characters are not always one byte.